# Linq to Entities group query giving list of results in each group

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

If I have a set of entities with 3 properties (Id, Type, Size) all of which are strings.

Is there a way using Linq to Entities where I can do a group query which gives me the `Size` + `Type` as the key and then a list of the related Id's for that `Size` + `Type`?

Example below of getting the count:

```
Items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Size, x.Type})
     .Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
```

but I am looking to get a list of the Ids for each grouping?

I am looking to see if it is possible using Linq-to-EF before I decide to iterate through this in code and build up the result instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get List of Ids for each group then you have to select `x.Select(r => r.Id)` like:

```
var result = Items.GroupBy(x => new { x.Size, x.Type })
                  .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Key = x.Key,
                        Ids = x.Select(r => r.Id)
                    });
```

Comment: I had to take out the `.ToList()` because Linq-to-EF didn't recognise it but this did the trick, thanks for the help.. it wasn't clear to me that the group result can also be queried, great.

Comment: @Pricey, Modified my answer accordingly, forgot about `ToList` support in Linq to entities.

Comment: This answer is kind of confusing if you don't know about GroupBy, i think a small explanation on that could help new users (like saying that GroupBy will create a list of key-value pairs where value is also a list of elements that have been grouped, and which also explains why you can do `x.Select(r => r.Id)` on that value list specifically)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to build up a Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string?>> in dotnet 6.0  according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0);
where we have the dictionary *Key* as {Size, Type} and *Value* the list of Ids, you can write:

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string?>> result = Items.GroupBy(item => new { item.Size, item.Type }
                                                       item => item.Id),
                                                       (itemKey, itemIds) =>
                                                       {
                                                            Key = itemKey,
                                                            Ids = itemIds
                                                       })
                                              .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x=> x.Ids);
```